# Probability using normal approximation

Tags: probability

According to the US National Center for Health statistics, **25.2%** of men and **23.6%** of women never eat breakfast. Suppose that 
random samples of **175** men and **175** women are chosen. Use the normal approximation to estimate the probability that the number 
of men who never eat breakfast is strictly higher than the number of women who never eat breakfast (in the chosen samples).

I don't know if they're useful at all, but so far I've been able to find the mean of the two numbers and the standard deviation. Can someone help me figure out my next step, please?

Answer (score 0):

1. The number of people who never eat breakfast in a sample of size $n$ has Binomial distribution $B(n,p)$ where $p$ is the "success" probability (25.2% or 23.6% in your case).
2. $B(n,p)$ can be approximated by the normal distribution $N(np, np(1-p))$
3. Since random variables $M$ (the number of matched men in the first sample) and  $W$ (the same for women) are independent

   $(M-W) \sim_{approx} N(n_mp_m-n_wp_w,n_mp_m(1-p_m)+n_wp_w(1-p_w))$

   $P\{M-W\le c\}=\Phi(\frac{c-(n_mp_m-n_wp_w)}{\sqrt{n_mp_m(1-p_m)+n_wp_w(1-p_w)}})$
4. So, in your case you need to find:

   $P\{M-W>0\}=1-P\{M-W\le 0\}=...=0.6363$